# what algorithm should I use?

Tags: algorithm

I'm fairly new to complex algorithms (been doing simple programs til now), and I'm trying to develop a program where the user can input a desired budget, and the program would search for the optimal products the user can purchase from each category.
example:

Products:
Shirt:
shirtA - $20
shirtB - $15
shirtC - $10
Pants:
pantsA - $30
pantsB - $25
pantsC - $20
Shoes:
shoesA - $20
shoesB - $15
shoesC - $10

User Input (budget): $60

Output:
shirtB - $15
PantsA - $30
shoesB - $15
total: $60

...or something like that. what kind of algorithm should I be researching for? I find this hard because I do not know where to begin in understanding what algorithm to use. See, this is for class, and our professor wants us to indicate what kind of algorithm we used. I think I can actually finish this if I just brute force trial and error this thing, but then I wouldn't know what algorithm I used. anyway, thanks guys.

Comment: Seems to be a variant of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Is it necessary that at most one item from each category (Shirt, Pants, Shoes) is selected?

Comment: Search for an optimisation algorithm. You'll want to look at the various types that exist, and figure out whether or not this problem falls within the exact type they can solve. Note that at worst, if this is a form of bin-packing problem, the optimal solution is NP-hard.

Comment: Why is the 15-30-15 option better than 20-20-20? (If you can answer this question, you are probably a good deal closer to finding the algorithm)

Comment: Note also that if one from each category must be selected this problem is easier than if it is unconstrained.

Comment: @tobias_k lol just typed this one quickly didnt really think it through, sorry for the incorrect output, but thanks!

Comment: @Marcin I will search for that, thank you!

Comment: @Codor yes, one product per category is a must. :)

Comment: What language are you using to implement this in? The problem is easily modeled as a 0-1 integer linear programming problem and if you don't want to reinvent the wheel there are a lot of ILP libraries out there. As a somewhat random example -- there are numerous spreadsheet add-ins (including a built-in one) that can solve such things and can be scripted with VBA, and a great many OR/MS (Operation Research/ Management Science)  textbooks which discuss formulating such things as spreadsheet models.

Comment: On second thought, I'm a bit puzzled. The categories provide no utility values; wouldn't it be feasible just to choose the respective cheapest item from each category? What exactly is the objective?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a variation of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem); instead of choosing whether an item is to be included in the solution, a choice must be made which item to take from each category. Although not explicitly stated in the Wikipedia article, the formulation in the question can be solved within a pseudopolynomial runtime bound via [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) by modifying the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem) for the basic formulation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a fun with Python's `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def solutions(dicts, value):
    return [keys for keys in itertools.product(*dicts) if sum(d[k] for d, k in zip(dicts, keys)) == value]

Shirt = {"shirtA": 20, "shirtB": 15, "shirtC": 10}
Pants = {"pantsA": 30, "pantsB": 25, "pantsC": 20}
Shoes = {"shoesA": 20, "shoesB": 15, "shoesC": 10}

print solutions([Shirt, Pants, Shoes], 60)
```

We generate all allowed combinations (one piece from each category) but we keep only these that give the required sum.